# Why does mvn 3.0.4 use -source 1.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 when I have Oracle JDK 1.7 installed?

Tags: maven, ubuntu, java

I have mvn 3.0.4 and Oracle JDK 1.7 installed on Ubuntu 13.04.  When I build an existing project I get

```
error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

This same project works on Windows 7 with JDK 1.7 and mvn 3.0.4 without modifying the pom.xml to tell it which version of Java to use.

Ubuntu has openjdk 1.7 installed, but I have Oracle JDK 1.7 in the path before openjdk.

What's wrong with maven on Ubuntu 13.04?

Thanks.

Comment: Type on console: `mvn -v` and `java -version` and post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed mvn 3.0.4 (Ubuntu packaged version) and installed 3.1.0 (from Apache web site) and it now works.  There must be a problem with the packaged version of mvn 3.0.4 for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell Maven to use JDK 1.5(???) to compile your source code explicitly. Declare Maven compiler plugin (maven-compiler-plugin) in your pom.xml file, like this :

**File : pom.xml**

```
<project ...>
<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.3.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.5</source>
           <target>1.5</target>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This isn't needed with the same versions of maven and JDK on windows 7.  I shouldn't have to clutter up ALL of my pom.xml files like this because of a problem with mvn 3.0.4 on Ubuntu.