# why my maven compiling project using java 1.3

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I'm using maven in my projects and my classes does not have any error but when i use `mvn compile & package` it gives me a various error as below:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project cassandra: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>   [ERROR] /home/mostafa/idea/clonedatabase/src/main/java/ir/apk/tm/db/cassandra/DB.java:[119,11] generics are not supported in -source 1.3
>
> [ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
>
> [ERROR] ArrayList List = new ArrayList();
>
> [ERROR] 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .

and the other errors is saying `for-each loops are not supported in -source 1.3 & static import declarations are not supported in -source 1.3 &annotations are not supported in -source 1.3`

my java version is `1.6` but i don't know why it is compiling my project using java `1.3` and i using intelliJ

also i set maven `jdk` and `jre` version to 1.6

Comment: The problem related to that more than old maven-compiler-plugin which you are using. Use a more up-to-date plugin version and of course configure the source/target appropriately.

Comment: Which Maven version are you using? I suspect that you are using quite old version of Maven has been installed from the OS package repository ([link to the possible related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869774/why-does-mvn-3-0-4-use-source-1-3-on-ubuntu-13-04-when-i-have-oracle-jdk-1-7-in)). Try to download the latest stable version from the Maven web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Maven compiles with `-source` and `-target` levels at Java 1.5.  So I suspect that your POM file is using the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to set the levels differently.

Take a look at [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html), and then see if your POM file has something similar.